# Ruby Mechanize: multiline value for textarea gets merged

Tags: ruby, mechanize

**EDIT:** upon further testing, it seems like the issue is site-specific and should theoretically work just fine.

---

Textarea values which should be on multiple lines are being submitted all on one line.

```
textarea_values = "value1\nvalue2"

form = page.form_with(:id => 'form_id_here')
form['my_textarea'] = textarea_values
submit = form.button_with(:value => 'Submit')
form.click_button(submit)
```

The value being submitted is `value1\nvalue2` instead of being on multiple lines as intended.

Is there another way to add form values that I can try?

Comment: Are you using single quotes in the actual code?

Comment: @mu is too short: that is correct, the value being submitted contains a literal `\n`

Comment: @Mark Thomas: I am doing double quotes

Comment: it is submitting like `my_textarea=value1%0Avalue2`. `\n == 0x0A`. so, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you really tried the code you posted here?

Well I have in a website that has internal messaging system, with two textfields and one textarea.

my initial sample code:

```
@page = @agent.get "thewebsiteItold"

form = @page.form_with(:id => 'form')

textarea_values = "value1\nvalue2"

form['to'] = "username"
form['subject'] = "somesubject"
form['text'] = textarea_values

button = form.button_with(:name => "send")

@agent.click_button button
```

Although the form had this html:

```
<form method="post" action="/somethingyoudontneedtoknow" name="header" id="form">
```

running my script returned this error:

```
in 'method_missing': undefined method `id' for #<Mechanize::Form:0x21efb98> (NoMethodError)
```

Ok, so I changed the id for name and got another problem: the

```
in `<main>': undefined method `click_button' for #<Mechanize:0x253f380> (NoMethodError)
```

Before you tell me, I double checked the contents of "button", which holded the correct button I wanted to press to fire the form action.

So I changed it accordingly to [these mechanize examples](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html) and the code worked well:

```
form = @page.form_with(:name => 'header')

textarea_values = "value1\nvalue2"

form['to'] = "username"
form['subject'] = "anotherboringsubject"
form['text'] = textarea_values

button = form.button_with(:name => "send")

@agent.submit(form, button)
```

and, well, it worked like expected:

[image: resulting message on chrome]

**Conclusion:**
Check if your original code is too far from what you posted us or the version of mechanize is the same as the [link](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/mechanize/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html) I passed before

Comment: Thank you for testing it, I should have done so myself... Upon closer inspection, I realized the issue seems to be site-specific and not associated with Mechanize itself.

Comment: Just for curiosity, can you tell what it was? Or is it too much specific?

Comment: Unfortunately it is an internal webpage not available to the public, sorry. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Like @nash in the comment I can't understand the problem in the example above. "\n" is a control character (the LINE FEED, line marker).

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

So there is nothing wrong with this notation unless you use single quoted strings (in which the escaping with "\" doesn't work).

If you get confused by such notation you also can use the HEREDOC notation in Ruby:

```rb
textarea_values = <<VALUES
value1
value2
VALUES
```

In indented code you also can use:

```rb
# ... code ...
  # ... code ...
    textarea_values = <<-VALUES
      value1
      value2
    VALUES
  # ... code ...
# ... code ...
```

The difference here is the hyphen in "<<-VALUES", which means you can set your HEREDOC ending tag also indented in the code. Be aware, that the values in this example have leading spaces/tabs, so you would prefer first example - it breaks the indentation of the whole code block but the value lines have no leading spaces then.

For huge textarea inputs I really prefer the HEREDOC notation, it makes things easier and more readable.

Further information about HEREDOC:

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#here_doc
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Ruby

Everything about Ruby strings usage:

- http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Strings_-_Creation_and_Basics